# How to parse an XML element that has an attribute inside it? Asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, parsing, xmlreader

XML file:

```
<weatherdata>
<forecast>

<time day="2017-04-18">
    <temperature day="-4.26" min="-6.54" max="-4.26" night="-6.54" eve="-4.26" morn="-4.26"/>
</time>

<time day="2017-04-19">
    <temperature day="3.51" min="-5.41" max="4.49" night="-0.63" eve="4.27" morn="-5.41"/>
</time>

</forecast>
</weatherdata>
```

I need to parse the file and get the correct  element depending on which day="xxxx-xx-xx" I want to use. Then when I have the right time, I would like to create new strings for temperature_day, temperature_min, etc. with their correct values.

I've tried dozens of XmlReader variants, and I want to use it because it seems like such a simple thing to do. Here's what I have so far. If I can name the "reader.Name ==" why can't I just ask for the attribute name as well?

```
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(URL);
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "time" && reader.HasAttributes)
        {
            // DATE comes from a asp.net calendar, the format is correct
            if (DATE == reader.GetAttribute("day"))
            {
               if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "temperature" && reader.HasAttributes)
                {
                    string temperature_day = reader.GetAttribute("day");
                    TextBoxTemp.Text = temperature_day;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I've tested the (URL) with a very simple XmlReader code bit and have confirmed it to work. I'm completely out of ideas now, the attribute INSIDE an element is screwing me over.

Comment: Do you really need to use `XmlReader` at all? LINQ to XML (`XDocument` etc) is *much* easier to use.

Comment: Note that your `if (... reader.Name == "temperature"...)` condition will never be true because you've already established that your reader is positioned on a node whose `Name` is `"time"`. That's the trick with using `XmlReader` -- it reads one node at a time. @JonSkeet's advice of using LINQ to XML is good, or even using the venerable `XmlDocument` might be easier to grasp.

Comment: Well, not necessarily. I had a look at XDocument and it looked much more complicated than XmlReader... Thought I could just name the attribute I'm looking for, but apparently I can't, unless I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: "it looked much more complicated than XmlReader" - it's really, really not. It's a *lot* easier to query a document that's already been loaded than working with a live parser. There are *lots* of questions about querying with LINQ to XML.

Comment: I'll be taking a look at LINQ to XML then, thank you both of you @JonSkeet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use XDocument instead of XmlReader much easier to query.

**first example**

some code where you have too loop thru the results that did return from the LINQ query. But since you only have one < time > element and one < temperature > element inside that you can better use the second example

```
       // Create XDocument and load in the file
        XDocument _doc = XDocument.Load("C:\\t\\My File2.txt");
        //select all time element where attribute day.Value == to any day you give it just change "2017-04-18" 
        var time = _doc.XPathSelectElements("/weatherdata/forecast/time").Where(c => c.Attribute("day").Value == "2017-04-18");
        // Get IEnumerable of temperatures in the time element
        var temp = time.Select(x => x.Element("temperature"));

        // loop temperatures and get the attribute value from the element
        foreach (var element in temp)
        {
            string day = element.Attribute("day").Value;
            string min = element.Attribute("min").Value;
            string max = element.Attribute("max").Value;
            string night = element.Attribute("night").Value;
            string eve = element.Attribute("eve").Value;
            string morn = element.Attribute("morn").Value;
            MessageBox.Show($"day:{day},\nmin:{min},\nmax:{max},\nnight:{night},\neve:{eve},\nmorn:{morn}");
        }
```

**Second example**

I get the first one of a query result, so you don't have to loop to get one element. It is a bit riskier because you can get a null reference exception when no elements are found. but by a simple if you can catch it before it will be thrown.

```
         // Create XDocument and load in the file my case it is the path "C:\\t\\My File2.txt"
        XDocument _doc = XDocument.Load("C:\\t\\My File2.txt");
        // Select all time elements where attribute day.Value == to any day you give it, just change "2017-04-18" 
        // And select the first one of that result as I aspect there is only one time a day
        var time = _doc.XPathSelectElements("/weatherdata/forecast/time").Where(c => c.Attribute("day").Value == "2017-04-18").FirstOrDefault();
        // Get the children of time element by using .Elements() and take the first one of that.
        // You only have one temperature element in a time element so it will take that one with FirstOrDefault();
        var temp = time.Elements().FirstOrDefault();
        // assign attributes values to string
        string day = temp.Attribute("day").Value;
        string min = temp.Attribute("min").Value;
        string max = temp.Attribute("max").Value;
        string night = temp.Attribute("night").Value;
        string eve = temp.Attribute("eve").Value;
        string morn = temp.Attribute("morn").Value;

        // control
        MessageBox.Show($"day:{day},\nmin:{min},\nmax:{max},\nnight:{night},\neve:{eve},\nmorn:{morn}");
```

**Result with day "2017-04-18":**

[image]

Comment: I won't close this down yet in case something unexpected turns up, but it seems this did the trick... I'll definitely look more into LINQ to XML now. Thanks a lot for the help and also for the documentation link.

Comment: Works just as needed, thank you again for taking your time to help! Marked as an answer